# Strange SKCameraNode instanciation failure

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I tried to create a camera node in my SpriteKit scene like this:

```
self.camera = SKCameraNode()
```

and it failed (`self.camera` was then `nil`). That was very strange until I tried:

```
let c = SKCameraNode()
self.camera = c
```

which then worked!

Could you explain why the first failed while the second succeeded? (Note: that everywhere else the code is exactly the same). Looks like a very strange bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `camera` property of `SKScene` is a weak variable. You'll need a strong reference to the `SKCameraNode` or it will be released.